# Selenium executeScript fails sometimes

Tags: selenium

i've created the following function to click elements

```
private WebDriverWait wait;
public void clickElement(By element) throws InterruptedException {

    // wait element is clickable
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));

    // driver.findElement(element).click();
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(element));

    waitForAjaxLoadScreenDisappear();
}
```

we click thousands of elements, but sometimes randomly an error occurs:

```
arguments[0] is undefined Command duration or timeout: 223 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26' System info: host: 'linux-1au3', ip: '192.168.1.194', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.1.10-1.23.1-desktop', java.version: '1.7.0_21' Session ID: 471aca55-ae19-439e-aaa2-b2ba970a1252 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=20.0}]
```

How can arguments[0] be undefined, when the wait.until has finished?

Comment: PresenceOfElementLocated doesn't mean it's fully loaded or clickable, right? my 2 cents is that the element is not in a clickable state causing your js to fail... wait for some attribute of the element to be loaded/present that indicates it's good to go and see if that makes a difference...

Comment: do you know a way in selenium to check if an element is clickable?

Comment: usually buttons have enable/disable attributes, so along with asserting it's visible you also might want to check if they are clickable/enabled... you should be able to do something like the below:

element.isEnabled()

Then you probably want to loop until it's true before interacting with the element...

Comment: it seems to improve things, do you want to create an answer with your tip?

Comment: created an answer, hope it helped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually buttons have enable/disable attributes, so along with asserting it's visible you also might want to check if they are clickable/enabled...

you should be able to do something like the below:

```
element.isEnabled()
```

Then you probably want to loop until it's true before interacting with the element...